# Are your finger muscles and tendons interconnected?

Tags: human-biology, human-anatomy, muscles

Are finger muscles and tendons interconnected? If they are interconnected, then if i exercise one finger will it train the other fingers since they are interconnected and share the same muscles in the forearm? (correct me if im wrong)

I have done some research but i cant find the answer for example(if your thumb joint is injured you should avoid using stress balls to exercise the other fingers, why?)

Comment: Welcome to SE Biology.  It is expected that you will demonstrate that you have done some research on your own before asking questions here.  For details, please check out the tour: https://biology.stackexchange.com/tour and then this help page on how to ask questions on this site: https://biology.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask.  ------ For example, have you tried searching for "hand anatomy muscles and tendons"?

Answer (score 2):

That's a really interesting question!  What might help you the most is reviewing hand and forearm muscle anatomy.  I have some examples that could help.  The flexor digitorum profundus and flexor digitorum superficialis are hand muscles that originate in the forearm region.  At the wrist they split into four tendons (so FDP has 4, FDP has 4) one for each non-thumb finger.  They help make a fist.  Then there are the intrinsic hand muscles.  One interesting example is the lumbricals, which originate at the FDP tendon and have a very specific action. 
To answer your question, I don't see any reason why exercising the four non-thumb fingers is recommended against, other than the possibility that you could be inadvertently moving/stressing the thumb.  I don't believe there is any connection between muscles of the thumb and non-thumb fingers, other than proximity of muscle/tendons.